# Why is my simple laravel query returning a recursion?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, recursion, eloquent

I have two Eloquent models which are in a one to one relationship: A `mission` has one `vehicle`, and a `vehicle` belongs to one `mission`.

I have set up the relationships in both of my Models as follows:

```
class Vehicle extends Eloquent {
    public function mission() {
       return $this->belongsTo('Mission');
    }
}

class Mission extends Eloquent {
    public function vehicle() {
        return $this->hasOne('Vehicle');
    }
}
```

I am trying to grab an entire mission & vehicle row based on the name of the vehicle:

```
        $results = Mission::with('vehicle')->whereHas('vehicle', function($q) {
            $q->where('name','Falcon 9 v1.0');
    });
```

I would expect this to work, yet it does not, and furthermore, returns a recursive `Eloquent\Builder` object which crashes my browser. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `get` to get the result:

```
$results = Mission::with('vehicle')->whereHas('vehicle', function($q) {
    $q->where('name','Falcon 9 v1.0');
})->get();
```